# C++ how to change the value of a

Tags: c++

here is the question I have, i got this code and it needs to write out 2, 5, 1, for the variables a, b, c.
But the catch is the main should not change, only the function. I managed to change the b to 5, but I really don't know how to change a to 2 without using pointeres.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int& function(int a, int* b, int c) {
    
    return *b;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    a = b = c = 1;
    function(a, &b, c) = 5;
    cout << a << " , " << b << " , " << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Every help will be highly appreciated.

I tried using pointers but the main should not be changed.

Comment: can you change the signature of 'function'?

Comment: The use of references and pointers here is bizarre to say the least.

Comment: Tip: `int& a` can make it mutable.

Comment: The professor must have discussed typical ways memory is allocated for local variables (namely: subsequent definitions lie, in one way or another, in each other's "neighborhood"). The professor probably wants you to use that knowledge and access the memory of a and c which are somewhere close to b, whose position is known inside function().

Comment: @pm100, no, i can't change the signature of the funcition.

Comment: in that case there is no 'legal' way to do it, there are horrific hacks that might work occasionally

Comment: If you cannot change the function signature, it is impossible to change the value of `a` and `c` as they pass-by-value and not pass-by-reference. That means the changes made within the function will be local and discarded as soon as the function scope goes out of scope.

Comment: @RohanBari see Jeffrey answer. Its doable, but nastily

Comment: @pm100 Yes, seen. Exactly.

Comment: @pm100 The problem is that the solution is not reliable as it might not work for everyone. For example, in my system, I'm getting `1, 5, 1` with a compilation warning — `warning: array subscript 1 is outside array bounds of 'int [1]'` and flags like `-std=c++20 -O3`. However, it works when optimization is omitted.

Comment: @RohanBari yup, a horrific hack that might work sometimes

Answer (score 3):

If you can't modify the function signature, then it is a terrible question. As written, it is impossible. The compiler is allowed to assume `a` will stay 1.

There's a kind of professors I've seen that would want you to turn in:

```
int& function(int a, int* b, int c) 
{
    b[1] = 2;
    return *b;
}
```

But this relies on UB, a specific architecture and *disabling* optimization. https://godbolt.org/z/rc1d9oqab

If you are allowed to modify the function signature, yeah, then pass a reference for `a`.

Comment: I'd turn in `1[b]` just for the pure chaos factor.

Comment: But OP doesn't say that they can't modify the function signature; Only that main shouldn't change. The task could simply be about reference parameters. Even then, it's rather weirdly staged exercise.

Comment: @tadman How about `a[b]` for good measure? Also, rename `a`, `b` and `c` to `arr`, `index` and maybe `_5` or so. Or name the middle parameter `_1`!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think we're on to something here!

Comment: @tadman On my implementation, `stderr-stdout` is also 1. There must be more :-).

Comment: @eerorika He says function signature can't be changed in a comment.